# Own mailserver for newsletters SPF record issues

Tags: email, spf

At our business we are running a server for sending newsletters. Setting up the server and sending bulk e-mails is not the issue. That's all working fine.

I run a test on www.mail-tester.com to see how good the mail will pass spam filters. But unfortunately, we are running stuck on the SPF records.

Our setup:

- ISP: Business fiber connection with fixed IP. The ISP has setup our hostname as "mail.ourbusiness.com" (fictional domain name)
- Website: Our website www.ourbusiness.com is hosted in a datacenter and has nothing to do with our ISP.

The following errors occur:

- You're not fully authenticated
- We found an SPF entry on your server but it has still not been propagated
- Your message is not signed with DKIM

[See list of the complete fault message.](http://pastebin.com/HvB4awac)

It say's that our business IP is successfully associated with mail.ourbusiness.com (so that's good).

Now my question: What should our SPF record be? I can find enough information about SPF records, but I have totally no clue of what I need to put into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oké, solved this issue regarding the SPF record. mail-tester.com has now validated the mail successfully and gives it a 8.8 out of 10.

I did the following in the DNS of our domain ourbusiness.com.

1. Added A record form subdomain mail.ourbusiness.com with the content the IP address of our ISP.
2. Added SPF record for subdomain mail.ourbusiness.com

**A record**

```
mail.ourbusiness.com A 123.123.123.123
```

** SPF record **

```
mail.ourbusiness.com TXT v=spf1 a include:mail.ourbusiness.com ~all
```